# converting a date to european format

Tags: javascript, xml, date, format

I am writing a script for automating XML data in Indesign. I currently have in the XML the date in American Format (MM/D/YY) but once I run the script in Indesign my goal is to have it be in European format (DD/M/YY). What can I add to my script in order to write a function that will convert any date formats to european formats? I hope this makes sense. I need help!

Answer (score 4):

i guess simply using

```
function convertDate(dateString) {
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    return date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth() + 1)+"/"+date.getFullYear();
}
```

just note european format does not use slashes but dots as far as i know so it should look like this
dd.mm.yyyy
not
dd/mm/yyyy
becouse it can be mismatched with us format

Comment: hmmm I added that at the end of my script and it isnt updating the dates - i will warn you i appreciate all this help but im so clueless..this was not in my job description haha

Comment: its a function you need to call this function at desired point to make it work, i dont know how actually your source code for this looks like so i cant tell you exactly

Comment: yea i dont even know where to begin this is frustrating. maybe i can smile my way out of this one lol. but is it even possible to do this. so in the XML it read (11/27/12) for example. but it changes every month but we have a generic script that does all the rounding of numbers and stuff. haha i sound so dumb right now i dont even know what to say ill stop wasting your time :)

Comment: so you should have already something working which is iterating those data and working with them right?

Comment: yep - but we don't want to have to manipulate the xml date every month. so it comes in from the data mart in american format. but we would like the European format once the script is ran.

Comment: well then you should alter those dates directly in your XML via script and then save it with eu format, is this you looking for?

Comment: Our goal is to not have to edit the XML every month. We get mass amounts of date..we import the XML in a document and then run a script and it does all the rounding/converting etc we need for the documents. So basically i suck and idk what im doing lol but you're a dear for trying to help :)

Comment: add script i gave you to that rounding and converting process

Comment: You need to add 1 to the month since it starts at 0-index.

Answer (score 2):

[How to format a JavaScript date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

[Return dd-mm-yyyy from Date() object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843050/return-dd-mm-yyyy-from-date-object)

```
var d = new Date().toLocaleDateString("uk-Uk");
```

**Output: 03.09.2021**

```
var d = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
```

**Output: 03/09/2021**

```
var d = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-UK").replace(/\//g, '-');
```

**Output: 03-09-2021**

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDate = new Date('myDateString'); //you can also do milliseconds instead of the date string
var myEuroDate = myDate.getDate() + '/' + myDate.getMonth + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
```

Useful as well...
http://arshaw.com/xdate/

Comment: How about http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp ... you can use the javascript Date object to construct your date string

Comment: Based on having half a naughty word in the URL?

Comment: ahha no clue crazy web blocker

Comment: I just am not good @ javascript and automating in Indesign..so im struggling lol but i want to solve this. Do I just add at the end of the script? basically I want (MM/DD/YY) to convert to (DD/MM/YY) anytime it appears in the document?

Comment: It would be helpful, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat