# Outputting Wrong Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem outputting the date in Javascript.
I want to output `2021-03-02T00:00:00+00:00` to March 2, 2021

```
export function parseDate(dateString) {
  const [date, time] = dateString.split(' ')
  return new Date(`${date}T${time}.000Z`) // Z = UTC
}

export function formatDate(dateString) {
  if (!dateString) return ''

  const date = parseDate(dateString)
  return date.toLocaleString('en', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  })
}



 console.log(formatDate(data?.createdAt))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510580/convert-string-to-datetime)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a function to get the UTC date in the Locale String Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427168/is-there-a-function-to-get-the-utc-date-in-the-locale-string-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on your expected output:

```js
const dataSource  = "2021-03-02T00:00:00+00:00";


function getYourDate(source){
  const date = new Date(source);
  const dd = date.getDate();
  const mm = date.toLocaleString('en',{month: 'long'});
  const yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  
  return `${mm} ${dd}, ${yyyy}`;
  }
  
  console.log(getYourDate(dataSource));
```

Comment: And you can change the appearance /output by changing the sequence at the return statement

Answer (score 0):

> Use **toLocaleDateString** method with following options as below:

```js
const toReadableDateFormat = (dateStr) => {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }
  return date.toLocaleDateString('en', options);
}

console.log(toReadableDateFormat('2021-03-02T00:00:00+00:00'));
```